# What happens to super handler with instance variables

Tags: mvc, codeigniter, instance

What will happen if I extend a class A to a controller B, when A has instance variables (private, protected)?

I have a main controller `MY_Controller`(handler) which has several methods: can_modify (can the user modify think?), has_permission, success, error (to build array of error messages).

Then there are specific controllers: `Admin_controller`, `User_controller`. Both extend My_controller.

It's working well for my needs but my question here is that I have instance variables in `MY_controller`. I know handlers are singleton so, is it a bad idea to put instance variables in the handler, even the super type?

Comment: Where did you get it from that handlers must be singletons? I have not encountered that as a requirement within MVC before.

Comment: Read it in a few StackOverflow comments.

Comment: It is perfectly fine for MY_controller to have instance variables.  The fact that within a typical php request/response application controllers tend to be singletons (no real point in making more than one instance) is irrelevant.

Comment: But then, is the controller that extends the Admin_controller still a singleton?

Comment: What exactly do you think a singleton is?  I suspect you a confusing it with something else.

Comment: Something stateless created only once and reused.

Comment: So why would you think that a controller that is only created once would not be a singleton just because it extends a particular class?  In most request/response scenarios, only one controller will be created and it won't be reused.